# How to get Repast Simphony started in Eclipse now that Groovy compiler 2.4 is officially unavilable?

Tags: repast-simphony

I am trying to get the Repast Simphony to work with the instructions from here https://repast.github.io/download.html#update-site-install
which clearly states that it would work only with Groovy Compiler version 2.4.x

However, in October 2020, support for the Groovy compiler has been officially dropped: https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/commit/454c669ab9649be2a87f449f7b9ea2eb29f7999e

Is there a way to get Repast Simphony to work with Eclipse anymore?

Comment: What Eclipse version are you trying to use? This should all work with the setup described here: https://repast.github.io/download.html#update-site-install  Eclipse 2020-06 and the e4.16 Groovy Eclipse plugin: https://dist.springsource.org/release/GRECLIPSE/e4.16

Comment: I am using Eclipse 2020-06 as instructed, however the Groovy Eclipse plugin has stopped it's support for Groovy Compiler 2.4. 
I was wondering if there are ways to use the old compiler with or without Eclipse?

Comment: If the answer below solved your issue please mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for finding this. You should be fine if you point to the update site from the previous version (v.3.9.0) of the Groovy Eclipse plugin: https://dist.springsource.org/release/GRECLIPSE/3.9.0/e4.16
We'll adjust the Repast Simphony Eclipse Update Site install instructions to reflect this.

(Adjusted the instructions here: https://repast.github.io/download.html#update-site-install)